# Label terms of LaTeX equation

Tags: equations, subequations

I'm interested in labelling my latex equation, by giving the physical phenomenon contributing to the term. For instance `x = f(y) + g(y)`. So a horizontal curly bracket to explain that `f(y)` is derived from some phenomenon, say resistance and `g(y)` is derived some other phenomenon, say gravity.

How can I give a name to `f(y)` as resistance and `g(y)` as gravity in the equation?
Hope I'm able to explain my intentions.

Thank you,
Aditya

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have `\underbrace` from `amsmath` and `\underbracket` from `mathtools` (which loads amsmath). I added some horizontal adjustment with the `\clap` command (from mathtools), since the labelled terms are short:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \[ x = \underbracket[0.8pt]{f(y)}_\text{\clap{resistance~}} + \underbracket[0.8pt]{g(y)}_\text{\clap{~gravity}} \]
    \[ x = \underbrace{f(y)}_\text{\clap{resistance~}} + \underbrace{g(y)}_\text{\clap{~gravity}} \]%%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Using the `amsmath` package, you can do this as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[x = \underbrace{f(y)}_{\text{resistance}} + \underbrace{g(y)}_{\text{gravity}}\]

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]